# Swift dictionary keys are integers

Tags: dictionary, swift3

I have an app that I'm converting from Swift2 to Swift3. One thing I need to do is the following:

```
dict.enumerateKeysAndObjects({ (key, rotationString, stop) -> Void in
    //code goes here to use key as an integer
)
```

How do I do that? Also, `rotationString` will also be an integer.

Background:
In the Swift2 version of the app I was saving data to defaults thusly:

```
func saveGame() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(blackRotations, forKey: "blackRotations")
    defaults.set(whiteRotations, forKey: "whiteRotations")
etc.
```

Here, `whiteRotations` and `blackRotations` were NSDictionary objects where the actual data being saved had keys that were NSNumbers and values that were also NSNumbers.

So, what I need to do is to handle loading the saved game from UserDefaults. The values for blackRotations and whiteRotations were dictionaries when the game was saved. The structure of this dictionary was a bunch of integer pairs. You can think of them as integer lookup tables saved as dictionaries.

So all I really am asking for is how to load this data from UserDefaults and be able to treat both the keys and values as integers.

Possible solution? I'm still working on trying to get this to work, but I'll post here anyway, in the hope that it will help to illustrate what I am trying to do.

In the method that loads the saved state, I think I need to do something along these lines:

```
        if let blackDict = (defaults.dictionary(forKey: "blackRotations") as? [String:Int]) {
            for (keyString, rotation) in blackDict {
                blackRotations[Int(keyString)!] = rotation
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's a method on `NSDictionary`, which is accessible in Swift 2 because the bridging between `NSDictionary` and Swift's native `Dictionary` was implicit. That isn't the case anymore.

Comment: what's wrong with `for (key, value) in dict {`?

Comment: `for (key, rotationString) in dict {...}`? It's unclear what you're asking – what's `dict` typed as?

Comment: Obviously, I don't know what I'm asking. My code, which worked in Swift2 does not work in Swift3 after converting to Swift3 syntax. I'm stuck right now on this dictionary thing.

From the comments, it looks like I should not be using NSDictionary. Correct? Is there a document somewhere I can read to guide me on changes I need to make from Swift2 to Swift3?

Comment: @Hamish, here is the declaration I had:

    var blackRotations:NSMutableDictionary = [:]
    var whiteRotations:NSMutableDictionary = [:]

Comment: @VictorEngel But what's `dict`? Regardless, you shouldn't use `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift, use a Swift `Dictionary` instead. For integer pairs, that'd be an `[Int : Int]`.

Comment: @VictorEngel Do not use – never do – `NSMutable...` in Swift. Use the native structs.

Comment: Sure (about mutable dictionaries), but that doesn't address my issue (I don't think). I'm reading NSUserDefaults, so what I'm getting is an NSDictionary, not a Swift Dictionary, right?

Comment: @VictorEngel Even if you need to used `NSDictionary` to interface with Objective C frameworks (like for using `NSUserDefaults`), you should just do a conversion at the point of the call, with `as NSDictionary` and `as [SomeKeyType: SomeValueType]`

Comment: @Alexander, maybe that's the point of what I'm asking. I don't know what to do what you just suggested. How about an example?

Comment: @VictorEngel I don't know what you're asking/what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe if I knew how to ask the question, I wouldn't have to ask it. My starting point is an NSUserDefaults object, which is an NSDictionary, by definition. The objects I'm interested in processing are also NSDictionary, which, as I understand it, is what I need to do because property lists can't store Swift dictionaries. The dictionaries I am reading are dictionaries were the keys and objects are all NSNumbers that were saved from integers. I need to be able to access these numbers and do math on them. That's it. Maybe what I need to do is convert an NSDictionary to a Swift dictionary?

Comment: @vadian, so how would you save a dictionary of `[Int:Int]` to a plist without using NSMutableDictionary? BTW, my last edit (code at bottom of question) worked.

Comment: Use `PropertyListSerialization`.